# How to loop in Python to update a dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have the following dicts:

```
{'company':'a', 'op':'buy', 'value':10}, 
{'company':'b', 'op':'buy', 'value':15},
{'company':'a', 'op':'sale', 'value':5}
```

... and I want a new updated dict to be generated

```
{'company':'a', 'value':5}, 
{'company':'b', 'value':15}
```

Note that if a sale has been made, it calculates to update 'value'.

I hope someone guides me to a solution!Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have two dictionaries in the end. You should explain how those dictionaries relate to the input dictionary.

Comment: For company B you have no `buy` and a `sale` of 15. Should its position be `-15` in the end?

Comment: There was a mistake of mine in the second dictionary. The correct is: {'company':'b', 'op':'buy', 'value':15}. Nesse caso, nada seria calculado nesse dicionario.

Comment: then edit your question with the correct details

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete 'op' field, use del dict['op']
if you want to update 'value' field, use dict['vp'] = x
for using a loop to update all dicts, you might need a list to store all the new values ordered by the dicts you want to update, and also have a list to store your current dicts, and update them.
sample code

```
updates = [5,10,15]
dicts = [{'company':'a', 'value':5, 'op':'buy'},{'company':'b', 'value':15, 'op':'sale'},.{'company':'c', 'value':20, 'op':'buy'}]
for i,update in enumerate(updates):
    del dicts[i]['op']
    dicts[i]['value'] = update
```